# PHP Warning: file_get_contents(http://ipecho.net/plain): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in

Tags: php, warnings, file-get-contents

I have an error here and I don't know where the problem is exactly.
I am trying to make a PHP file and deny anyone to use the script except the IP that I have entered into the code:

```
$pass = '192.168.x.x'; //here is the ip of the client
if (file_get_contents('http://ipecho.net/plain') !== $pass) {
```

When I use the code Ii have problem

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://ipecho.net/plain): failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Is `allow_url_fopen` enabled ?

Comment: Does it get the contents of the URL? Firewalls etc. If so - what is the contents

Comment: the contents  must be just  a ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use that site for getting the client's IP?

You can use this PHP function for getting the client's IP address.

whenever the application is behind a proxy(e.g, Cloudflare):

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

and when the application isn't behind a proxy:

```
function get_client_ip() {
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Final code should be like this:

```
$pass = '192.168.x.x'; //here is the ip of the client
if (strcmp(get_client_ip(),$pass) == 0 ) {
```

Comment: This is bad advice. Nobody has to be behind a proxy, just send in an http header and they could pretend to be localhost.

Comment: You are right! This function should always be used for applications behind a proxy

Comment: It would still be incorrect even if behind a proxy. Nginx, Cloudflare etc they just add multiple X-Forwarded-For headers instead of dropping source one, not to mention internal proxies on a cloud deployment

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_get_contents('http://ipecho.net/plain') !== $pass)
```

Please note that using this code you are comparing ip of your SERVER with pass not your CLIENT !

so your code is wrong. another problem is in using '!==', it's something that you should only use on boolean types not strings 
so the quick fix is :

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $pass)
```